# how to get onclick value from input data value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to get onclick value from input data value and execute that function

my html code

```
<input type="hidden" id="navi" value="shownext(1,2);">
<input type="button" id="next" onclick="next();">
```

my java script

```
function next(){
    var nq=document.getElementById('navi').value;
    {
    document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() { 'nq' };
}
}

function shownext(td,id){
//code
}
```

when i click next button its not clicking navi function

Comment: `'nq'` is not a statement. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `next` with your `nq` parameter:

```
document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() { next(nq); };
```